# How to increase label/axis font in WaveletComp's wc.image?

Tags: wavelet

The default font size is extremely small (too small for publication), and I read the manual looking for this feature with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the font size using `cex` and `cex.lab` within `par()`